# javascript google maps semantic zoom

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am currently trying to implement semantic zooming similar to the way shown in Mike Bostock demonstrates in [this d3 example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3680957) with the [circle markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/circle-simple) in the javascript google maps api. I cannot figure out how to change styles (radius, opacity) of these markers after they have already been created on the zoom action. Is there a way to do this without removing them and then recreating them with a different size?

```js
  // Overlay for eruptions

  for (var eruption in eruptions) {
    var coordinates = new google.maps.LatLng(eruptions[eruption].Latitude, eruptions[eruption].Longitude);
    var eruptionCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
      class: 'marker eruption',
      strokeColor: ERUPTION_COLOR,
      strokeOpacity: marker_border_opacity(),
      strokeWeight: 2,
      fillColor: ERUPTION_COLOR,
      fillOpacity: marker_opacity(),
      map: map,
      center: coordinates,
      radius: eruption_size(eruptions[eruption].VEI),
    });
    ERUPTIONS.push(eruptionCircle);
  }

  map.addListener('zoom_changed', function() {
    var zoomLevel = map.getZoom();

    // TODO - need to find a way of semantically zooming on these markers


  });
```

Comment: What have you done so far and what does it do, vs what you want it to do?

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: so far its the same as the example [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/circle-simple) except with about 2000 more circles. The goal is that when you zoom in the circles should cover less area on the map so that they can be distinguished better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use setOption

```
   eruptionCircle.setOptions({radius: eruption_size(yourNewRadius)});
```

You have a mistake too (remove the last `,` form option this way

```
var eruptionCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
  class: 'marker eruption',
  strokeColor: ERUPTION_COLOR,
  strokeOpacity: marker_border_opacity(),
  strokeWeight: 2,
  fillColor: ERUPTION_COLOR,
  fillOpacity: marker_opacity(),
  map: map,
  center: coordinates,
  radius: eruption_size(eruptions[eruption].VEI)
});
```